# How is this statement not contradictory?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $$C = v_0, v_1,...,v_k, v_0$$ be a longest circuit in $G$. Suppose $C$ is not a Eulerian circuit.

By longest circuit don't they mean every vertex is visited? How is this different than a Eulerian circuit?

PS I think $G$ is connected, unless I misunderstood the text.

Comment: 1. No, consider a graph that is a cycle with a path hanging off one vertex. The longest circuit is the cycle, which does not visit the vertices on the path. 2. Even if the circuit did visit all the vertices, it need not be an Eulerian circuit, because an Eulerian circuit must visit all the *edges*.

Answer (score 3):

No, *longest circuit* means exactly what it says: $G$ does not contain any circuit longer than $C$ (though it may contain some other circuit that is equally long. Even if $G$ is connected and has a circuit, it need not have an Euler circuit, but it will definitely have a longest circuit. The graph on five vertices shown below has circuits of lengths $3$ and $4$, so its longest circuit if of length $4$ (around the diamond), but it has no Euler circuit.

```
             *  
            /|\  
           / | \  
          *  |  *-----*  
           \ | /  
            \|/  
             *
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, each Eulerian circuit is trivially a longest circuit, as it omits no edges and hence can not be enlarged.

But note, that, if a graph has a circuit, then there is always a longest circuit (as the size of a circuit is bounded by the number of edges). Hence, each *non-Eulerian forest* (a graph, that has no Eulerian circuit and is not circle-free) yields a counterexample, e.g:

```
 A--B--D
 | /
 |/
 C
```

Certainly, $A-B-C-A$ is a longest circuit, but not Eulerian, since it does not use the edge $BD$.